# Generating a transferable QGIS report template for clients

Tags: qgis, print-composer, reports

The company I work for is aiming to provide feature reports to clients, containing several fields on data collection information and feature characteristics/values such as location, height/width and images of each feature.

All data is collected using a template GeoPackage, so I assume transferring the report template between projects should be relatively straight forward.

When the template is loaded into a new project, the report template initially opens as it should, with all tables etc having the correct columns. However, under item properties when you set the source layer to the project, it resets the formatting and adds all attributes to the table.

Is there a way of locking report template attributes, so the report can be transferred between different projects?

Other than manually selected the required attributes for each table, is there a quicker way to lock the table attributes so each time the template is opened with a new project, the formatting doesn't reset?

I assume it should be straight forward but I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template file is connected to layer via layerid in the project where you have built them and not connected with layer name. When you try to use a template in a new project there is no layer with the same layer id so the connection is lost and as a new source the table will show all the columns.

**A solution :** share a project file with the report integrated.

A project could use data in a GeoPackage based on relative path. In a folder put your GeoPackage data structure and create a qgis project using this data. After that, create your report as you wish and save the project.

Then, you can move your project file (`.ggz` or `.qgs`) next to other GeoPackage data sources, and it will use it to make your report when you open it. (your data structure must be the same).

Comment: That makes sense have made the changes and it appears to be working well! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great !  @jt1998 , if it solve your problem you can mark my answer as solution (green check) and vote UP.